# Omitting metacharacters in python

Tags: python, metacharacters

I want to assing a path to a variable a:
`a = "D:\misc\testsets\Real"`

How can i omit the `\t` metacharacter without changing the folder name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use raw strings:

```
a = r"D:\misc\testsets\Real"
```

Answer (score 0):

### Try this:

- `r` denotes raw string.

```py
a = r"D:\misc\testsets\Real"
```